# How to create register and user profile page using scaffold or columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I am new to Rails, and I want to make sure I start off on the right foot. So I need some clarification.

My required register fields will be Username, Email, Password, Birthday, Zip Code.

So I will be running "rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string, birthday:string zip code:string". I will then add a password_digest column to the user_spec file.

My profile fields that I will allow for users to enter after registering from their User CP is: Name, Gender, Ethnicity (option to select more than one), Email, Password, Birthday, Zipcode (not in US then list city, country), education, religion, politics, children, height, does user smoke, does user drink, career and the user about me section.

What I need confirmation is should I be generating scaffold for all of this information (User for the required information, then create another scaffold called UserProfile for the additional profile info) or should I just use columns inside the user_spec.rb for essentially all that information?

Comment: I would expect `spec/models/user_spec.rb` to be an Rspec test for the `User` model found in `app/models/user.rb`. If you start using Rspec to test your code (and you don't have to use Rspec, but you should test) and you're using names like `*_spec.rb` elsewhere, you might find those names confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual database columns will be defined in the database migration file. You don't need to define them all in the model definition. If you build a scaffold for a model using the generator as you describe, you'll find a migration file in `db/migrations` which creates the columns you describe.

It sounds like you're thinking of "scaffolds" as actual code, which is confusing. Think of scaffolds, instead, as blueprints which define the creation of model code, controller code, and view code. You don't generate scaffolds; you generate models, views, and controllers using a scaffold.

Comment: Ok. I just wasn't too clear if it is necessary to do it all from the generate scaffold or if I should just edit the files afterwards to add that information. I essentially wanted to make sure I am doing things the most efficient way. Trying to learn the best methods while learning the code at the same time.

Comment: Yeah - you don't need to add all your fields when you generate the scaffold, you can generate migrations to add them later. Most Rails projects will have quite a few migrations to tweak the data tables as the project develops.

Comment: Thanks. Out of quick curiosity. When I enter zip codes in the command because that is one I am including in scaffold. Should I enter it with a underscore or closed space (zip_code or zipcode)?

Comment: That's personal preference - you can use either. Ruby convention is not to use hyphens or CamelCase in that context, but whether you break the words with an underscore or not is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to keep all the fields in one table. This can be done using migration easily.

After adding all the fields including Username, Email, Password, Birthday, ZipCode,Name, Gender, Ethnicity (option to select more than one), education, religion, politics, children, height, does user smoke, does user drink, career and the user about me section.

Then you can imply the condition after login and before login to **show/hide** the fields according to what you want.

The general way to do that is:

```
if current_user

//show the fields after login
else
//show the fields before login
end
```

Note that it is a general idea of how you could do that. However you can use it anywhere in your code in any view.

Comment: So with that method I would generate scaffold User with all that profile information and then use show/hide in return to display what I want to be shown on the register page and edit profile page correct?

Comment: yes that is what I have written because it doesn't matter when you are showing what. The thing is to use condition based on what you want and when you want.

Comment: Ok that will work perfect then so I don't have to create another scaffold called UserProfile. I can instead just use the User one with your show/hide tip.

On another note, for zip code when I enter that in for scaffold. Should it zip_code, zipcode or zip code?

Comment: yes correct. It also depends on what you are trying to achieve and that is what we say database management. So suppose user has many posts then its not a good idea to keep posts field in user table. So you create posts table with `user_id` as a `foreign key` and a relationship like user has_many posts. This will also help to solve many conditions easily.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to rails, but I would not recommend the Scaffold option. You would do better to generate a User model and Users controller from the command line with desired fields, and then create your views as you need them.

Scaffolding will probably give you more than what you need and lead to confusion/problems down the road.

You should check out Michael Hartl's "Learn Rails by Example" (free as an ebook!). Even if you don't want to work through it, he guides readers through building a Twitter app and I think reading some of the chapters would be helpful to you. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I have heard some people say to skip scaffolding and just do it all by hand. Others say they use it but end up deleting several unneeded files.